# character array from function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm facing a confusing problem, I have a function that returns a character array I try to read that and print it out, but the output seems to be garbage values

```
char  *ssl;
ssl = router_con.get_ssp_IO('1',this->no_io_l1);

for(int qq=0;qq<this->no_io_l1;qq++)
{ std::cout<<ssl[qq]<<"\n";
}
```

get_ssp_IO function is as follows

```
char*  TCP_IP_Connection::get_ssp_IO(char level,int id)
{
int ctr,ss=0;
char sspi[id];
for(int a=0,ctr=0;a<this->len;a++)
  {
if(this->data[a]=='?')
{
    do
    {
        a++;
    }while(this->data[a]!='\n');
}
else if(this->data[a]==' ')
      {
     ctr++;

        if(ctr==3)
       {
            sspi[ss]=this->data[a+1];

            ctr=0;
            ss++;
       }

       }

    }
  return(sspi);
}
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing?

Comment: And how about show function get_spp_IO?

Comment: yes, we would really appreciate this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further detail my suspicion is that `get_ssp_IO(....)` looks like this:

```
.... get_ssp_IO(....) {
    char ret[some_length];
    ....
    return ret;
}
```

but the array memory is undefined once the function returns. As you are in C++, you should use `std::string` instead, which would free you from all memory management issues.